# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context ... on line 7

Tags: php

I've searched stackexchange, but everything is suggesting what I'm doing is correct. Line 7 is `$captchacode = $this->createCaptcha();`

```
class Problem
{
    public function createForm(){

        $captchacode = $this->createCaptcha();
        $return = $captchacode;

        return $captchacode;
    }

    private function createCaptcha(){
        require_once('/php/recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php'); // from the reCaptcha page
        $publickey = "6Le2Ze4SAAHERFHU34T7FGEoEjVI-rwdJcVKE7p9"; // from the reCaptcha page
        return recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    }
}


$problem = new Problem();
echo Problem::createForm();
```

Comment: The function is declared static

Comment: I've updated the code. I still get the same error, plus `Strict standards: Non-static method Problem::createForm() should not be called statically ... on line 22`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking the method in a static way:

```
echo Problem::createForm();
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---static call
```

`$this` is not available when in "static mode".

If you'd had

```
$problem->createForm();
```

instead, which is the object invocation method, then it'd work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `$this` in a static function.

Comment: I still get the same error plus this one, `Strict standards: Non-static method Problem::createForm() should not be called statically ... on line 22`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function createForm(){
    return self::createCaptcha();
 }
```

Try this instead

Comment: Please care to explain why? so that helpful to understand.

Comment: @Digital_Reality: `self::...` is the mechanism for accessing a static (possibly inherited) method.  The OP began with `static` code, and this is one way to continue on that path.

Comment: @abiessu Agree.. but my whole point was answer should have its own explanation.

Comment: @Digital_Reality: good point, although in the absence of the answerer posting a good explanation, we can choose to not vote on the answer and offer good explanations in the comments...